# Unable to create a template

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I am trying to create a dataflow template using the below mvn command And i have a json config file in the bucket where i need to read different config file for each run(i dont want to hard code values`) the code is as below

During the template creation im getting below error for all the 3 args which i have passed for getSchemaJson method
`Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context.`

Can some one help me if it is possible to send args at runtime for the getSchemaJson method

```xml
-Dexec.mainClass=com.mainClass \
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
-Dexec.args=" \
--project=project \
--stagingLocation=gs://001test_data_flow/staging \
--tempLocation=gs://001test_data_flow/temp \
--templateLocation=gs://001test_data_flow/templates/dataflow.json \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--region=region"``

public static String getSchemaJson(ValueProvider<String> projectId, ValueProvider<String> bucketName, ValueProvider<String> filename) {
       String fileContent;
       try {
           Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(String.valueOf(projectId)).build().getService();
           Blob blob = storage.get(String.valueOf(bucketName), String.valueOf(filename));
           fileContent = new String(blob.getContent());
           return fileContent;
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           LOG.error("Exception Occurred While Processing Schema!!"+e.getMessage());
           return null;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses classic Dataflow templates, and it has several limitations. The biggest one (and what's also affecting you) is that they can't support dynamic  parameters. That means, all the parameters MUST be available at the time of running.

The reason is, Dataflow generates a compiled template with the DAG and gets uploaded to `--templateLocation`. This file contains the parameters provided when triggering the job. So, each step of the job (in the DAG) should be pre-determined, so they shouldn't have dynamic values. So, the value for `filename` should be passed at the time of triggering.

This is fixed by [Flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates), where the compiled template is generated **after** the job is triggered! The code is enclosed in a Docker image and the pipeline DAG is generated using a separate process (called the launcher VM). Since the compiled template is generated there, we can pass dynamic parameters to the job and it is evaluated by this launcher VM.

So, it's advised to use Flex Templates for production level pipelines.

I wrote [an article](https://gnomezgrave.com/2020/11/21/dataflow-flex-templates-and-how-to-use-them/) on getting started with Flex Templates for a Python codebase, but it should work more-or-less the same for Java.

Comment: Thank you for your response and it worked when we use the flex template

Answer (score 0):

The `ValueProvider` values are only supposed to be accessed at runtime. You are trying to access these values during the pipeline construction time resulting in the error. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates) for the correct way to define/use ValueProviders for Dataflow classic templates.

Alternatively, you can define a [Dataflow flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) which eliminates the need for ValueProviders.

Comment: Thank you for your response and it worked when we use the flex template